# How do I set a grid as focues using a IsMouseOver trigger?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to bring focus to a Grid element that is the base of an xaml file when I hover over it with the mouse.  I have the following code and it is not currently setting the focus.

```
<Grid x:Class="MyApp.MyClass"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=trackPlot:MyViewModel}}"
         Focusable="True" 
         Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    ....Grid Contents here....
</Grid>
```

The first two triggers are just there to make it obvious that the Grid has been focused on and work if I tab onto the grid.  The third trigger is where I am trying to set the focus and it is not functioning.

Comment: It works fine in empty project. Can you provide more detalied xaml?

Comment: That works in an empty project...now time to figure out what the diff is.  Sorry to bother everyone by not trying that first.

Comment: Are you sure your grid contents are not in the way?

Comment: I've figured this out....I'll update my question with the additional info and the answer shortly.  If anyone can explain why it works this way I will award them the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I suggest you to use RelativeSource.Self in FocusedElement binding :

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

I think the reason is that binding expression searches element by element name without check target element name itself.

I can also provide my full example if its needed.

Comment: This works, and has the added benefit of getting rid on an element.  And it reminds me of how to do self referencing without a name.  Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you would want something like:

```
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
   </Trigger>
```

Comment: IsFocused is not a writable property.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to add an additional Grid layer and trigger on that.  I have no idea why you can't use the base element of the file, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<Grid x:Class="MyApp.MyClass"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
     d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=trackPlot:MyViewModel}}">
    <Grid Focusable="True" Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        ....Grid Contents here....
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```